# C# sprite movement pos-x double

Tags: c#, xna

Im working on a XNA project. I have drawn a background(skyline) and i want to move a cloud from left to right. This works whenever i use int, but the movement is too fast so i want to use a double. Is it possible to move the cloud on the x with a double?

```
public int GetRandomSpeedX() // Random speed pos-x
{            
        int speedX = r.Next(1, 100);
        return speedX;
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
        if (cloudX <= 500)
        {
            cloudX += GetRandomSpeedX();
        }
        else
        {
            cloudX = 0;                
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

If i use a double it says: cannot implicitly convert type double to int

and i cant change the cloudX to a double because the spriteBatch function wants int only!

any help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be sufficient enough to reduce speedX? `r.Next(1,10)`?

Comment: i used those to see if my random function worked, i want the cloud to move on x with between 0.5 and 2.0

Comment: Just use one of the `Vector2` overloads instead of a `Rectangle`. [`SpriteBatch.Draw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433991.aspx)

Comment: private void DrawCloud()
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(cloudTexture, new Rectangle(cloudX, 0, cloudWidth, cloudHeight), Color.White);

        } Can you help me how to?

Answer (score 1):

My XNA might be a bit rusty, but you will need two variables for your Cloud, Position and Speed. You will change the Speed each update to increase the Position of the cloud.

Here is a basic implementation. You'll need to setup up the initial Position and Speed in your game initialization.

```
private float NextRandomFloat(double max, double min)
{
    var number = r.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;

    return (float) number;
}

private Vector2 GetRandomSpeed(float dx, float dy)
{
    var speedX = NextRandomFloat(2.0, 0.5) * dx;
    var speedY = NextRandomFloat(2.0, 0.5) * dy;
    var vector = new Vector2(speedX, speedY);

    return vector;
}

private Vector2 cloudSpeed;
private Vector2 cloudPosition;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
        if (cloudPosition.X <= 500)
        {
            // Tinker with the dx to manage acceleration
            // Consider using MathHelper.Clamp for a maximum speed.
            cloudSpeed += GetRandomSpeed(1.0f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            cloudSpeed.X = 0;
        }

        cloudPosition += cloudSpeed;

        base.Update(gameTime);
}

private void DrawCloud()
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(cloudTexture, cloudPosition, Color.White);
}
```

Comment: +1 - Don't forget to factor in gameTime.ElapsedGameTime for your movement just in case you can't maintain the target FPS.

Comment: Good suggestion I completely forgot. It's been awhile since I've thought about game dev. I might need to get back into MonoGame.